# using exist realm database

Tags: java, android, database, realm

I have an existing realm db and I need to read and query it.
I used the following code to assing it as default realm obj so that when ever I call Realm class it points to my db but when I use getDefalutConfiguration() method it doesn't returns my assigned db. instead it returns the defult.realm db which has made internally.
this is the colde:

```
Realm.init(this);
RealmConfiguration realConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
        .assetFile("assets\\databases.realm")
        .readOnly()
        .build();
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realConfig);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `asserFile` is used as initial database for the database by copying it to the location according to the configuration, but only if the file does not already exist. Are you sure that there are not already an existing `default.realm` present?

Comment: I need to first copy my db to device then read it from database folder of app on device then be able to query or filter data...and yes i think there were a default.realm file...how can I initialize my own db then?